# Setup Zurb Foundation 6 (sass) in Laravel 5 using composer

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, zurb-foundation-6

I am starting a new `Laravel` project with `v5.2` and I would like to use `Zurb Foundation v6.2`.

I've seen that Zurb Foundation can be installed through `composer` and since I've installed `Laravel` through `composer`, I thought it as a good idea.
I did it, Foundation is in the `vendor` (`vendor/zurb/foundation`) folder.

It has also been added to the composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "zurb/foundation": "^6.1"
},
```

But now, how can I use it? Where should I create my css file(s)? In the `resources/assets/sass` folder where Laravel already provides a scss file (app.scss)? If so, how can I link it to Zurb Foundation?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Hi @hendra, I finally use the npm method to do the install, not sure it's the best solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) is more suitable for this purpose.

From the guide:

> #### Installing Node
>
> Before triggering Elixir, you must first ensure that Node.js is installed on your machine.
>
> ```
>  node -v
> ```
>
> By default, Laravel Homestead includes everything you need; however, if you aren't using Vagrant, then you can easily install Node by visiting their download page. Don't worry, it's quick and easy!
>
> #### Gulp
>
> Next, you'll want to pull in Gulp as a global NPM package like so:
>
> ```
>  npm install --global gulp
> ```
>
> #### Laravel Elixir
>
> The only remaining step is to install Elixir! With a new install of Laravel, you'll find a package.json file in the root. Think of this like your composer.json file, except it defines Node dependencies instead of PHP. You may install the dependencies it references by running:
>
> ```
>  npm install
> ```

Then to install *Foundation 6 for Sites* it's recommended to use [Bower](http://bower.io/), (another) package manager, but specifically for managing frontend facing libraries like Foundation and jQuery.

You can have a look at [Zurb's example template](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template) for better understanding.

```
npm install --global bower
```

Create a file named `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-site",
  "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "~6.1.2",
    "motion-ui": "~1.1.0",
    "foundation-sites": "~6.2.0",
    "motion-ui": "~1.2.2"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "private": true
}
```

Then run `bower install`.

In `app.scss`, import Foundation:

```
@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

Then in `gulpfile.js`, compile it to CSS:

```
mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css/app.css', {
  includePaths: [
      'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/'
  ]
});
```

Finally to compile, run:

```
gulp
```

Comment: I realised that I didn't actually answer your question - how to use the Composer-installed Foundation - I'll do that shortly (though I'm not to familiar with doing this approach)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I did not manage to install Zurb Foundation with neither bower or npm... I managed only with composer... but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I'm confused as to the purpose of using yet another tool in the form of Elixir. Are you saying it's not possible to use Foundation for PHP with `composer`? This seems weird considering `composer` is the industry standard package manager for PHP.

Comment: @Prometheus Since this was a Laravel application and Laravel already provided a dedicated frontend tool for this purpose, I thought it would make sense to use it... at the time. However fast-forward to today 4 and half years later and Elixir is dead along with Bower, Gulp is no longer the preferred tool. Yet Composer is still very much alive.

Answer (score 0):

I think npm way is better suited for front-end stuffs. Take a look at this:

http://somethingnewtutorial.blogspot.com/2017/07/using-foundation-6-with-laravel-5.html

If you are using earlier version, its just using gulp instead of laravel-mix.